# Adding icon to product listing image based on attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, if

I am trying to place a text icon on relevant product listing images based on an attribute value ('In Stock'). Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, as I am crashing the page with the current code.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('in_stock')==$this->_('In Stock')): ?>
 <div class="product-img-icon-quick">IN STOCK</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code above is being placed in the relevant area of list.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was as simple as missing the __ double underscore in the php code above.